# stackView not expanding according to to the dynamic label content

Tags: ios, uistackview

[image: image 1 constraints]
[image: image 2]

I am using stackView to show the hierarchy shown in image1. The two labels are in vertical stack view and then this stack view with the image is combined in an horizontal stackview.

I set the description label no of lines to 0 and make it workWrap
but as this the cell is not expanding according to data.

Comment: How you are managing cell height?

Comment: did you set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` so that the tableView would allow growing it?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: @Saad Chaudhry & @ Milan Nosáľ I am using "tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension" to automatic managing cell height

Comment: show the rest of your code

Comment: What are the distribution and alignment of the stack views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it solved by adding the both labels in view. Everything else is same.

Select both label -> Editor -> Embed In -> View